# ordinary differential equation with 'initial value' specified as a limit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I am working with an ordinary DE of the form $y'=F(x,y)$, where $F$ is $C^{1}$ on $(0,1]^{2}$. If given initial condition in $(0,1]^{2}$, this would be a standard problem for which we know solution exists and is unique. The complication arises since I have 'initial condition' of the form $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}y(x)=0$.

Question: Is this studied and hence understood problem (in terms of solution uniqueness, mainly)? Any hints, references etc. will be appreciated.

What I have done so far was to read relevant chapters from [King, Billingham and Otto](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Differential-Equations-Nonlinear-Ordinary-Partial/dp/0521816580/ref=sr_1_1/258-0401011-0152550?ie=UTF8&qid=1495115925&sr=8-1&keywords=Billingham%2C+King%2C+Otto+-+Differential+Equations%2C+Linear%2C+Nonlinear%2C+Ordinary%2C+Partial) and from [Birkhoff and Rota](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ordinary-Differential-Equations-Garrett-Birkhoff/dp/9812530029/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1495115954&sr=8-3&keywords=Birkhoff%2C+Rota+-+Ordinary+Differential+Equations) so that I am familiar with the 'standard' solution existence, uniqueness, continuity and comparison theorems for ordinary DE (with initial conditions).

I would love to provide more about the context, but find it hard to do so concisely. I am working on a research project in which I am looking at war of attrition model(s), that admit description of equilibrium strategies via differential equations. The domain $(0,1]^{2}$ for $F$ arises due to 'types' that are random variables: $F$ is a ratio of *cdf*s that becomes undefined for the (lowest) zero types. That is, unfortunately, my problem cannot be dealt with (redefined away) by changing the model.